# Tangent to ellipse using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw 2 ellipses and a 6-sided polygon that is inscribed in the first ellipse and circumscribed about second ellipse. I am working with package Tikz and I am a beginner, so this is as far as I got:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\clip (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\coordinate (A) at (170:2 and 1);
\coordinate (B) at (100:2 and 1);
\coordinate (C) at (40:2 and 1);
\coordinate (F) at (220:2 and 1);
\coordinate (E) at (-90:2 and 1);
\coordinate (D) at (-30:2 and 1);
\coordinate (X) at (intersection of A--E and D--B);
\coordinate (Y) at (intersection of A--F and D--C);
\coordinate (Z) at (intersection of C--E and F--B);
\draw[black,thick] (0,0) ellipse (2 and 1);
\draw[black,thin] ($(A)!-0.0!(B)$)--($(A)!1.0!(B)$);
\draw[black,thin] ($(C)!-0.0!(B)$)--($(C)!1.0!(B)$);
\draw[black,thin] ($(C)!-0.0!(D)$)--($(C)!1.0!(D)$);
\draw[black,thin] ($(F)!-0.0!(E)$)--($(F)!1.0!(E)$);
\draw[black,thin] ($(E)!-0.0!(D)$)--($(E)!1.0!(D)$);
\draw[black,thin] ($(A)!-0.0!(F)$)--($(A)!1.0!(F)$);
\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D,E,F}
  \fill[black] (\p) circle (0.04);
\draw[black] ($(A)+(120:0.3)$) node{$A$};
\draw[black] ($(B)+(100:0.3)$) node{$B$};
\draw[black] ($(C)+(90:0.3)$) node{$C$};
\draw[black] ($(D)+(-90:0.3)$) node{$D$};
\draw[black] ($(E)+(-80:0.3)$) node{$E$};
\draw[black] ($(F)+(-110:0.3)$) node{$F$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

So this gives me the outer ellipse, 6 points on it, and the tangents to the inner ellipse. But I am stuck, as I don't know how to draw the inner ellipse.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It would be helpful for those who might help you, if you embed your code in a small, self-contained example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  That shows the environment you're working in, so helpers can copy-and-paste the example to experiment directly.

Comment: Is there any other condition imposed on 2 ellipses and 6-sided polygon? I am not sure the existence of such configuration!

Comment: I agree with @BlackMild. You have six real parameters to specify the locations of the six points on the outer ellipse. The inner ellipse has only five parameters: the x and y coordinates of its center, the two "radii" and a rotation angle. So one might expect that the system is overconstrained.

Comment: To confirm the two previous comments, you can read https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3063637

Comment: If there isn't a closed form solution, one can always express it as a least squares problem and use nonlinear optimiization to find the best fit.  OTOH, I would look at triangles using 3 of the five points and see it they have anything in common.